# Can I create one pdf with multile lex files?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am writing a long lex file, and getting tired of scrolling up and down. So does anyone know if there is a method that can allow me to write multiple short lex files and combine them to generate one pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\input{sub_file}` in your main tex file to include the latex content of the `sub_file` in the main file:

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
        \input{section1}
\end{document}
```

Sub file {section1}:

```
\subsection{A subsection}
Some \LaTeX{} to fill the section
```

Comment: Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include